# Querying Parquet file in HDFS using Impala

Tags: hdfs, parquet, impala

I'm trying to read a parquet file with Impala.

```
impala-shell> SELECT * FROM `/path/in/hdfs/*.parquet`
```

I know I can do that using Spark or Drill, but I wonder if it's possible with Impala ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a structured `table` on top of the `parquet` files to query via Impala.

General example of `external table` pointing to parquet directory ... Cloudera docs provide all methods here:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_parquet.html#parquet_ddl

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ingest_existing_files LIKE PARQUET '/user/etl/destination/datafile1.dat'
  STORED AS PARQUET
  LOCATION '/user/etl/destination';
```